# Appending at run-time to a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, runtime, append

I have a function named `OpenAccount()` which takes in the details from the User and appends it to my database dictionary.

I have a database file(module) which is imported in my function file.

I have a function called AppendRecord(key,**dictvalues) which appends values to my database file.

However I am not able to call the function and take in values at run-time to append.
It works fine with Hard-coded values.I'm posting the code.Please help me out.

```
def AppendRecord(key, **dictvalues):
      salesDept[key] = dict(dictvalues)
```

and the call for hard coded values is ...

```
AppendRecord('Jill',Name='Jill', Acctype='Savings')
```

Now when I' trying to take in all the values along with the key from the user,I am not able to call the function.I'm just a beginner at Python so please pardon me for any errors:

**Edited Code:**

#!/usr/bin/python

```
import os       #This module is imported so as to use clear function in the while-loop
import DB                       #Imports the data from database DB.py

def AppendRecord(key, **dictvalues):
        DB.Accounts[key] = dict(dictvalues)

def OpenAccount():           #Opens a new a/c and appends to the database   data-base.

        while True:

                os.system("clear")      #Clears the screen once the loop is re-invoked

#Parameters taken from the user at Run-time so as to make entries in the database and append them


                print '\n','Choose an Account Type'

                print '\n','\n1)Savings Account','\n2)Current Account'

                choice = input('Enter an optin: ')

                if choice == 1:

                        name = raw_input('\nEnter a name: ')
                        depo = input('\nEnter amount(Rs.): ')
                        key = raw_input('\nEnter an alphanumeric-id: ')
                        acc= raw_input('\nEnter the Account-Type: ')

                        AppendRecord(key,Name=name,Initial_deposit=depo,Acctype=acc)
```

**EDIT 1:**
The Errors I get are.

```
 File "/usr/lib/python2.5/shelve.py", line 124, in __setitem__
    self.dict[key] = f.getvalue()
TypeError: 'int' object does not support item assignment
```

**EDIT 2:**

Following is the **DB.py**  database file source code.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import shelve                   #Module:Shelve is imported to achieve persistence

Victor = {'Name':'Victor Hughes','Acctype':'Savings'}
Xavier = {'Name':'Xavier Bosco','Acctype':'Savings'}
Louis = {'Name':'Louis Philip','Acctype':'Current'}
Beverly = {'Name':'Beverly Dsilva','Acctype':'Current'}

Accounts = shelve.open('shelfile.shl')          #Accounts = {}

Accounts['Louis']= Louis
Accounts['Beverly']= Beverly
Accounts['Xavier']= Xavier
Accounts['Victor']= Victor

Accounts.close()
```

Comment: What goes wrong? are there any error messages? Also, you have a typo (I think, you would be getting an error otherwise) in your hard coded call. You should only be quoting the Savings and not the whole keyword argument.

Comment: aaronasterling -- I corrected the typo. Thank you.I have added the Error message,please check EDIT 1.

Comment: We need the traceback or some more details on "not able to call the function" so that we can help you. :)

Comment: @Noufal Ibrahim--I have just posted that part of my source code which isn't functioning because posting the entire code would be too tedious for everyone to figure out.Also I just edited my question ,please check it.Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide the code where self.dict is defined or first assigned?

Comment: Pavitar. We need the exact line in your code that's triggering the error. At the very lease, please post the entire traceback. The traceback you've posted gives us an exception raised in the stdlib shelve module which is because of bad data passed in. We need information on from where (i.e. your code).

Comment: My interpretation of """self.dict[key] = f.getvalue()
TypeError: 'int' object does not support item assignment"" is that `self` is an int :-O  ... **FULL UNEDITED TRACEBACK please**

Comment: @Pavitar, the code that you posted is useless. Please remove it and replace it with the code for the DB module which is where the problem lies. @John Machin I hate to get into this game with you again but If `self` was an `int` then it wouldn't have a `dict` atttribute and you'd get an `AttributeError`

Comment: @aaronsterling: You win. It's `self.dict` that's the int. This code: `self_dict = 666; self_dict['foo'] = 'bar'` raises that error.

Comment: Please remove junk like "EDITED: OK here is the actual problem.".  Please focus on your question and edit your question to be one, direct, clear, complete question.  We don't care about history.  Stack Overflow maintains a complete change log.  Please **simplify** and **focus**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that the `DB` module is closing the shelf before you write to it.  Get rid of the last line and it will work fine.

You will also need to provide a function to close it or do so manually.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import shelve                   #Module:Shelve is imported to achieve persistence


Accounts = 0

Victor = {'Name':'Victor Hughes','Acctype':'Savings'} #???
Xavier = {'Name':'Xavier Bosco','Acctype':'Savings'}
Louis = {'Name':'Louis Philip','Acctype':'Current'}
Beverly = {'Name':'Beverly Dsilva','Acctype':'Current'}


def open_shelf(name='shelfile.shl'):
    global Accounts
    Accounts = shelve.open(name)          #Accounts = {}
    # why are you adding this every time? is this just debugging code?
    Accounts['Louis']= Louis
    Accounts['Beverly']= Beverly
    Accounts['Xavier']= Xavier
    Accounts['Victor']= Victor


def close_shelf():
    Accounts.close()
```

You will now need to call the `DB.open_shelf()` function before you write to it and the `DB.close_shelf` function when you are done. I would recommend calling them at the beginning and end of your program respectively.

You'll note that this is really just wrapping `shelve` and adding pretty much zero value. I would scrap the whole `DB` module and just use `shelve` directly.

Comment: Yes this just a debugging code.+1 Thankyou it works fine with your answer.But when I try to read from 'shelfile.shl',I do not see the appended values. :( I'm confused